# Unique constraint on PAIR of values, MySQL

Tags: mysql

I tried to do this in phpmyadmin sql: `ALTER TABLE 'table' ADD UNIQUE ('field1', 'field2');` but it failed saying that there was a duplicate value for field1, which is correct. What I want is a constraint that doens't allow for pairs **field1 and field2** to coexist in the same row. Field1 might have multiple instances of it has well as field2, but not simultaneously. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Apparently the problem is due to NULL values in the table... anyone knows how I can avoid this, keeping the null values?

Comment: Can you post the DDL used for the table creation?

Comment: unique constraints are a 0/1 condition. "the following indexed fields can exist together in a record AT MOST once". You need a 0, which can't be done with an index. this'd normally be done with a constraint, but mysql doesn't support them. YOu'd need to add a bunch of triggers to your table to  catch insert/update and disallow matched pairs from getting into the table in the first place.

Comment: @MarcB: nitpicking: MySQL *does* support "constraints" (foreign key, primary key) but not **check** constraints.

Comment: not so sure about that: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp but then im not into mysql

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger: w3schools is full of errors. You should delete that from your bookmarks and never visit it again. In this case they failed to mention that MySQL will *pretend* to add that check constraints but in reality it ignores it.

Comment: As i said im not into mysql. however what is a database worth without checks?

Comment: You really have to write triggers to accomplish this?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger: yes, that's the only way. Apparently many people can live with that limitation (and many more) in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

For adding an unique key on multiple columns you just have to do that:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`column1`, `column2`, `column3`);
```

is this what you wanted ?

Comment: This is exactly what the OP said didn't work when they tried.

Comment: unless among these data there is a duplicate, it is strange that it does not work

Comment: It works just don't use the commas.   (Worked on mine anyway)